# How to create a responsive div on image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position:relative;
}
.tag {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: -10px;
    background-color: green;
}
.mytag {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 60px;
    top: -10px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="tag">Featured</div>
     <div class="mytag">My list</div>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200">
</div>
```

I'm trying to create a div on image, but i'm not able to create a responsive one.

I'm trying to create a replica of this website as i'm a beginner. I want to create the first section, which should be a responsive one (plan and design and our goal should be on the image) How can i achieve the same? [check here](http://digitalorchestrators.testyourwebsites.com/)

How to make it a responsive?

Comment: Share your code or else no once can help you. Just a suggestion, you can always look at layout of any website by going to debugger mode. Try implmenting divs same way as website did.

Comment: As @CodeMan said, try looking into the debugger mode. The easiest way would be to put the image as a background.

Comment: @CodeMan i have edited it with the code. I want to make it a responsive one. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

The website you have mentioned uses a background image, Here is an example of achieving it.

First create your wrapper div and then apply a background image for it. make it relatively positioned. Make the other child content boxes `absolute` positioned. so you can move them freely using `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` css acttributes within its parent

**html**

```
<div class="div-with-bg-img">
  <div class="content-div">
   content here
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.div-with-bg-img {
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150);
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.content-div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: tomato;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 40px;
}
```

if you want to make it responsive then apply relative measurement units

```
.div-with-bg-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150) no-repeat;
    margin-top: 100px;
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Use media queries to make your website responsive

Here is an example code

```
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) { 
}
```

Few useful articles I found on web

[List of media queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

[What is RWD](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/)

If you just want to know how to make an image responsive here is a nice article published on css tricks

https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-css/

You can use the browser dev tools to learn the website source codes :)

Comment: Thank you. But How can we make them responsive completely  ?

Comment: You could use css media queries to target different view port sizes, device widths etc to make your website responsive